# Conan installed GoogleTest undefined refence in Debug mode

Tags: c++, cmake, googletest, conan

I installed GoogleTest with Conan. I can compile and run tests in Release mod but Debug mod gives undefined reference errors.

CMakeLists:

```
# For now, we build as executable, in the future make it library
add_executable(test-engine-mdh main.cpp)

# Finds absl when installed system wide.
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra -pthread")
#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wall -Wextra -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address,undefined -ggdb3 -pthread")
#set(CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG} -Wall -Wextra -Wno-error=deprecated-declarations -pthread -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=address,undefined -ggdb3")

target_include_directories(test-engine-mdh PRIVATE "include/")

include_directories(${GTest_INCLUDE_DIR})

target_link_libraries(test-engine-mdh
        Threads::Threads
        GTest::gtest
        GTest::gtest_main
        GTest::gmock
        GTest::gmock_main
        # ... Any other linked libraries
        )
```

I installed libraries with `conan install . --output-folder=cmake-build-debug --build=missing && conan install . --output-folder=cmake-build-release --build=missing`

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

TEST(test, initial) { EXPECT_EQ(1, 1); }

auto main(int argc, char **argv) -> int {
  ::testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
  return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

My main cmakelists file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

# Specify your project's name
project(berg-mdh)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

Error output in the debug mode:

```
> ====================[ Build | test-engine-mdh | Debug ]=========================
> /home/ocpalo/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/CLion/ch-0/231.9011.31/bin/cmake/linux/x64/bin/cmake
> --build /home/ocpalo/dev/berg-mdh/cmake-build-debug --target test-engine-mdh -j4 [1/1] Linking CXX executable test/test-engine-mdh
> FAILED: test/test-engine-mdh  : && /usr/bin/c++ -m64 -g -m64
> test/CMakeFiles/test-engine-mdh.dir/main.cpp.o -o test/test-engine-mdh
> && : /usr/bin/ld: test/CMakeFiles/test-engine-mdh.dir/main.cpp.o: in
> function `test_initial_Test::TestBody()':
> /home/ocpalo/dev/berg-mdh/test/main.cpp:3: undefined reference to
> `testing::Message::Message()' /usr/bin/ld:
> /home/ocpalo/dev/berg-mdh/test/main.cpp:3: undefined reference to
> `testing::internal::AssertHelper::AssertHelper(testing::TestPartResult::Type,
> char const*, int, char const*)' /usr/bin/ld:
> /home/ocpalo/dev/berg-mdh/test/main.cpp:3: undefined reference to
> `testing::internal::AssertHelper::operator=(testing::Message const&)
> const' /usr/bin/ld: /home/ocpalo/dev/berg-mdh/test/main.cpp:3:
> undefined reference to
> `testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper()' /usr/bin/ld:
> /home/ocpalo/dev/berg-mdh/test/main.cpp:3: undefined reference to
> `testing::internal::AssertHelper::~AssertHelper()' /usr/bin/ld:
> test/CMakeFiles/test-engine-mdh.dir/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
> /home/ocpalo/dev/berg-mdh/test/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to
> `testing::InitGoogleTest(int*, char**)' /usr/bin/ld:
> test/CMakeFiles/test-engine-mdh.dir/main.cpp.o: in function
> `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
> /home/ocpalo/dev/berg-mdh/test/main.cpp:3: undefined reference to
> `testing::internal::GetTestTypeId()' /usr/bin/ld:
> /home/ocpalo/dev/berg-mdh/test/main.cpp:3: undefined reference to
> `testing::internal::MakeAndRegisterTestInfo(char const*, char const*,
> char const*, char const*, testing::internal::CodeLocation, void
> const*, void (*)(), void (*)(), testing::internal::TestFactoryBase*)'
> /usr/bin/ld: test/CMakeFiles/test-engine-mdh.dir/main.cpp.o: in
> function `RUN_ALL_TESTS()':
> /home/ocpalo/.conan2/p/gtestbc86fe4528d89/p/include/gtest/gtest.h:2314:
> undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()' /usr/bin/ld:
> /home/ocpalo/.conan2/p/gtestbc86fe4528d89/p/include/gtest/gtest.h:2314:
> undefined reference to `testing::UnitTest::Run()' /usr/bin/ld:
> test/CMakeFiles/test-engine-mdh.dir/main.cpp.o: in function
> `testing::internal::SuiteApiResolver<testing::Test>::GetSetUpCaseOrSuite(char
> const*, int)':
> /home/ocpalo/.conan2/p/gtestbc86fe4528d89/p/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:528:
> undefined reference to `testing::internal::IsTrue(bool)' /usr/bin/ld:
> /home/ocpalo/.conan2/p/gtestbc86fe4528d89/p/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:528:
> undefined reference to
> `testing::internal::GTestLog::GTestLog(testing::internal::GTestLogSeverity,
> char const*, int)' /usr/bin/ld:
> /home/ocpalo/.conan2/p/gtestbc86fe4528d89/p/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:528:
> undefined reference to `testing::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog()'
> /usr/bin/ld:
> /home/ocpalo/.conan2/p/gtestbc86fe4528d89/p/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:528:
> undefined reference to `testing::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog()'
> /usr/bin/ld: test/CMakeFiles/test-engine-mdh.dir/main.cpp.o: in
> function
> `testing::internal::SuiteApiResolver<testing::Test>::GetTearDownCaseOrSuite(char
> const*, int)':
> /home/ocpalo/.conan2/p/gtestbc86fe4528d89/p/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:549:
> undefined reference to `testing::internal::IsTrue(bool)' /usr/bin/ld:
> /home/ocpalo/.conan2/p/gtestbc86fe4528d89/p/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:549:
> undefined reference to
> `testing::internal::GTestLog::GTestLog(testing::internal::GTestLogSeverity,
> char const*, int)' /usr/bin/ld:
> /home/ocpalo/.conan2/p/gtestbc86fe4528d89/p/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:549:
> undefined reference to `testing::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog()'
> /usr/bin/ld:
> /home/ocpalo/.conan2/p/gtestbc86fe4528d89/p/include/gtest/internal/gtest-internal.h:549:
> undefined reference to `testing::internal::GTestLog::~GTestLog()'
> /usr/bin/ld: test/CMakeFiles/test-engine-mdh.dir/main.cpp.o: in
> function `testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperEQ<int,
> int>(char const*, char const*, int const&, int const&)':
> /home/ocpalo/.conan2/p/gtestbc86fe4528d89/p/include/gtest/gtest.h:1375:
> undefined reference to `testing::AssertionSuccess()' /usr/bin/ld:
> test/CMakeFiles/test-engine-mdh.dir/main.cpp.o: in function
> `testing::AssertionResult testing::internal::CmpHelperEQFailure<int,
> int>(char const*, char const*, int const&, int const&)':
> /home/ocpalo/.conan2/p/gtestbc86fe4528d89/p/include/gtest/gtest.h:1359:
> undefined reference to `testing::internal::EqFailure(char const*, char
> const*, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,
> std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, bool)'
> /usr/bin/ld:
> test/CMakeFiles/test-engine-mdh.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV17test_initial_Test[_ZTV17test_initial_Test]+0x20):
> undefined reference to `testing::Test::SetUp()' /usr/bin/ld:
> test/CMakeFiles/test-engine-mdh.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTV17test_initial_Test[_ZTV17test_initial_Test]+0x28):
> undefined reference to `testing::Test::TearDown()' /usr/bin/ld:
> test/CMakeFiles/test-engine-mdh.dir/main.cpp.o: in function
> `test_initial_Test::~test_initial_Test()':
> /home/ocpalo/dev/berg-mdh/test/main.cpp:3: undefined reference to
> `testing::Test::~Test()' /usr/bin/ld:
> test/CMakeFiles/test-engine-mdh.dir/main.cpp.o:(.rodata._ZTI17test_initial_Test[_ZTI17test_initial_Test]+0x10):
> undefined reference to `typeinfo for testing::Test' /usr/bin/ld:
> test/CMakeFiles/test-engine-mdh.dir/main.cpp.o: in function
> `test_initial_Test::test_initial_Test()':
> /home/ocpalo/dev/berg-mdh/test/main.cpp:3: undefined reference to
> `testing::Test::Test()' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
> ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

Comment: Please don't quote the formatted compiler text, use a code block for compiler messages.

Comment: *I can compile and run tests in Release mod* It's unbelievable, the shown libraries GTest::gtest_main GTest::gmock_main when are used both should make it impossible.

Comment: I would guess is a misconfiguration error. The Conan profile must match with you cmake defines. For example, `conan install .. -pr=debug` (or just -s build_type=Debug) should follow `cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug && cmake --build . --config Debug`. Plus, you should consume cmake files produced by Conan, like FindGTest.cmake. Take a look on the tutorial and follow the same steps, only replacing your favorite package reference: https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/consuming_packages/build_simple_cmake_project.html

Comment: Thanks, i did solve my problem with custom debug profile!